# c# Invalid Cast checkstate value from database

Tags: c#, casting

i have a function that return settings :

```
public DataTable check_settings()
{
    Data_access.Access_Layer Layer = new Data_access.Access_Layer();
    Layer.Open();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = Layer.SelectData("check_settings", null);
    Layer.Close();
    return table;
}
```

this table return a row : 
Checked or unchecked as a result

what i want is to take this result and make as settings :

```
DataTable _table = new DataTable();
_table = Option.check_settings();
options.Capital.CheckState = (CheckState)_table.Rows[0][0];
options.MailConfirm.CheckState = (CheckState)_table.Rows[0][1];
options.Notifications.CheckState = (CheckState)_table.Rows[0][2];
```

and then i got the error Invalid Cast

Comment: If by check state you mean checkbox's checkstate you should cast it or ideally convert it to a boolean.

Comment: obviosly table.Rows[i][j] can not be parsed to CheckState explicitly.

Comment: Even if it returns the Value Checked Or unchecked with (Checkstate) ?

Comment: Right click in VS on Access_Layer and select 'definition'. Check type of SelectData to make sure it is a DataTable.  Then check columns to make sure columns 0 - 2 are CheckState objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Works as Boolean

I changed the Data Type IN Sql From VarChar to BIT 
and in my code :

i changed the **CheckState** to **Checked**

```
    options.Capital.Checked = (Boolean)_table.Rows[0][0];
    options.MailConfirm.Checked = (Boolean)_table.Rows[0][1];
    options.Notifications.Checked = (Boolean)_table.Rows[0][2];
```

and it works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what data is in your table there's no way to really know a proper solution, but you might want something like

```
options.Capital.CheckState = _table.Rows[0][0] ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;
```

The comparison just needs to make sense based on the actual data from your table.

Comment: I Already added the Value Checked / Unchecked in the table on my database ?

Comment: But as what data type? As an int or a string? If they are int values then they should be able to cast to the enum. If that's the case then maybe your data contains a value that isn't between 0 and 2. Run your code in debug and when you get the error inspect the value and type of the value in _table[][].

Comment: Converted To False or True , and i converted the value as boolean too

Comment: I updated my answer, which would work if the data type was a boolean. I also saw you changed the code to use options.Capital.Checked, which would also work with a boolean.